# `SQLite does not exist` despite Mono.Data.Sqlite added as reference in Xamarin on OS X

Tags: c#, macos, sqlite, mono, xamarin-studio

In Xamarin Studio on Mac OS X 10.10.2 I wrote a C# class that uses `SQLiteConnection`.

Xamarin complained about not knowing the class so I added `using System.Data.SQLite;`

Then when compiling Xamarin said:

```
The type or namespace name `SQLite' does not exist in the namespace `System.Data'.  
Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (CmisSyncContextMenu)
```

So I opened `Edit References` and added the `Mono.Data.Sqlite`:

[image]

I clicked OK, pressed `Rebuild all` and... I get the exact same error message as above.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open References in the Solution window and double click Mono.Data.Sqlite you will see that it does not use the System.Data.Sqlite namespace but the Mono.Data.Sqlite namespace.

So you will either need to change the using statement in your code or use a different version of the Sqlite assembly, perhaps from NuGet.

Comment: "*open References in the Solution window and double click Mono.Data.Sqlite*": Do you mean double-clicking `Mono.Data.Sqlite` in the project's References, which means the highlighted item in my question's screenshot? Double-clicking on it does nothing.

Comment: That worked! I changed the `using` statement in my code from `System.Data.SQLite` to `Mono.Data.Sqlite` and now it compile and run fine.